# Excel to calculate if values in ranges meet certain criteria using VBA

Tags: excel, vba, if-statement, range

I have two ranges in excel, say:

```
x   |    y
------------
 5  |   -1
46  |   -4
 2  |    1
67  |   -1
22  |    1
 6  |    0
34  |    0
 7  |   -2
```

I want calculate the sum of the second column for values less than O only if the respective values in the first column is less than 10 (i.e  `sum(y(i)` for `i<0` and `x(i)<10`) .  Hence in this case the sum will be -3.

Comment: Did you try putting this into an `SUMIF` statement?

Comment: is "less than O" as in some number O or, 0 as in zero?

Comment: sorry i meant 0 as in zero

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming your headers are in A1:B1 and your data is A2:B9 use this:

```
=SUMIFS(B2:B9,A2:A9,"<10",B2:B9,"<0")
```

Comment: Thnaks. But how can this be since for x(i)=1 then y(i)=-1 and x(i)=7 then y(i)=-2. Hence total -3

Comment: I had mistyped the data into the sheet - it works correctly if the data is correct. :o)

Answer (score 0):

Try something like

```
Function calc() AS Integer

    Dim sum AS Integer: sum = 0
    Dim c AS Range

    For Each c In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(1).Range("A1:A15")
        If c.Value < 10  And c.Offset(0, 1).Value < 0 Then
            sum = sum + c.Offset(0, 1).Value
        End If
    Next c

    calc = sum

End Function
```

Comment: Thanks for the prompt answer. If  we however assume that range("a1:a15") is the first column then isn't the  offset function going to take values from the cell on the right column? In this case it will only satisfy one criterio which is not what I want! Moreover how can I do the calculation without using offset. I prefer to have ranges which I will name.Thank you

Comment: I assume I want something like that: Function data_range() As Integer

    Dim sum As Integer: sum = 0
    Dim c As Range
    Dim y As Range

    For Each c In Range("range_x")
        If c.Value < 10 Then
      For Each y In Range("range_y")
      If y.Value < 0 Then
      sum = sum + y.Value
        End If
        Next y
        End If
    Next c

    calc = sum

End Function       However when i try that I get the value 0

Comment: Well I found out that macro is not necessary as I can use =SUMIFS(range_x;range_y;"<10";range_x;"<0"). However any suggestion how I can implement that in vba? Thanks

Comment: you could use [Worksheet Functions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/hh211481(v=office.14).aspx) WorksheetFunction.SumIfs(...)

Comment: Do you want some code to insert the formula into a cell or do the same thing in code?

Comment: Do the same thing in code. Ideally instead of having to write the range names in the code I would rather have a function such as data_range("range_x";"range_y") which would do the same things as SUMIFS(range_x;range_y;"<10";range_x;"<0").

Comment: I have set up a code to use sumifs Function data_range() As Variant

    Worksheets("Sheet1").Activate
   

    data_range = Application.SumIfs(range("range_x"), range("range_x"), "<0", range("range_y"), "<10")
    
End Function However what i am looking for is something like Function data_range1(y As range, x As range) As Variant

    Worksheets("Sheet1").Activate
   

    data_range = Application.SumIfs(x, x, "<0", y, "<10")
    
End Function. Or something like that since for this code I get a VALUE# error. I want my choose my ranges from excel and not from having to set them up in vba.

Comment: @yiannis you should ask it as another question rather than discussing in comments, that way more people are likely to see it and will be able to read the code better etc.